# Sending multithread message with socket and data from file

Tags: c#, multithreading

I want to send message with socket and data from file without recurring.
Example :

> Line 1 from file -> thread 1
>   Line 2 from file -> thread 2
>   Line 3 from file -> thread 3

I have tried send message with multi thread but i do not know how to read file with multi thread and send message without recurring data.

Here is my code

```
    {

        string request = "message to client";
        Byte[] bytesSent = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(request);
        Byte[] bytesReceived = new Byte[256];
        string page = "";
        //Create a socket connection with the specified server and port.
        server = "IPServer";
       int port = Portserver;
        using (Socket s = ConnectSocket(server, port))
        {

            if (s == null)
                return ("Connection failed");

            // Send request to the server.
            s.Send(bytesSent, bytesSent.Length, 0);

            // Receive the server home page content.
            int bytes = 0;
            // page = "Default HTML page on " + server + ":\r\n";
            page = "";
            // The following will block until the page is transmitted.
            do
            {
                bytes = s.Receive(bytesReceived, bytesReceived.Length, 0);
                page = page + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesReceived, 0, bytes);
            }
            while (bytes > 0);
        }

        return page;
    }
```

Comment: What problem are you solving by introducing multiple treads? Both operations: file reading and transferring data are bad candidates for multithreading, unless you have some processing of data don't do this. Send complete file with single thread.

Comment: i want to load test if i send multiple message together. I have 100 listener in server

Comment: Refactor above code into a method with `string` parameter (what will be sent). Then just read input file line by line and create new threads to run said method for each line.

Comment: public string SocketSendReceive(string server)
{
}
Do you mean like this? Thank you